# Bash Program hangs after if statement

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to bash and I have a program that sorts a csv file then prints it or saves it based on input. But it keeps on hanging on it after the if statement for the saving.

```
if [ "$1" = "-f" ]; then
    sort -r -t, -k5 $1>sorted.csv
elif [ "$2" = "" ]; then
    sort -r -t, -k5 $1
fi
```

should it not be sorting the file $1 and saving it to sorted.csv? The elif work?

Comment: echo statements are you best friend

Answer (score 5):

`sort` is waiting for data. Did you redirect the CSV file into the script? Or did you in fact mean to pass `"$2"` to `test`?

Comment: ... Or sort `"$2"` instead of `$1` (which should also properly be in double quotes)?

Comment: The lack of a space between `$1` and `>` is causing `$1` to be treated as a file descriptor for redirection, not as an argument to `sort`. It's waiting on standard input as a result.

Answer (score 3):

The first if test looks at parameter $1 and does something when that parameter is '-f'. That something is using the *same* parameter in the 'sort' call which evaluate to:

```
sort -r -t, -k5 -f > sorted.csv
```

This will hang as you would have to pipe into the script the file content you wanted sorted and saved in sorted.csv. I suppose when it hangs you could always just type in the csv file contents and finish with CTRL-D :-). The'-f' would do a fold-case sort on my machine.

If what you meant was to pass in a file name:

```
if [ $# -gt 1 ]
then
   if [ $1 = "-f" ]
   then
      # assume $2 not a control switch for sort but a file name
      sort -r -t, -k5 $2 > sorted.csv
   fi
fi
if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
   # assume $1 not a control switch for sort but a file name
   sort -r -t, -k5 $1
fi
```

Comment: Variable interpolations as file names should basically always be double quoted. You want `"$1"` pro `$1` throughout, and ditto `"$2"`.